# How to change IntegerField to CharField in Django for populated database?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I need to change model field type from IntegerField to CharField. My database is already in production. When applying migration, the following error is being shown:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='room',
            name='number',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=32),
        ),
    ]
```

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.

I have a solution but it seems tedious to me:

- Suppose, 'number' is IntegerField. I want to change it to CharField. Create new CharField 'number_char', clone data from IntegeField 'number', delete 'number' and rename 'number_char' as 'number'.

What is the most elegant way of doing this in Django?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the migration you are trying to apply.

Comment: updated @DanielRoseman